# Not able to update a pivot table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update the many to many pivot table that I have. I'm not sure how to go about it. I've tried to research it, but I'm not coming up with anything.

So what happens is when the user wants to edit a banner and they click on the frames that they would like to go with the banner it will update the pivot table to have the frames ID.

My tables look like this

Banner table

```
id  | title
1   | Banner 1
2   | Banner 2
3   | Banner 3
4   | Banner 4
```

Frames table

```
id   | title
1    | Frame 1
2    | Frame 2
3    | Frame 3
4    | Frame 4
5    | Frame 5
```

my banner_frame (My pivot table)

```
id  | banner_id | frame_id
1   |   1       |   1
2   |   2       |   2
3   |   2       |   3
4   |   3       |   3
5   |   3       |   4
6   |   4       |   1
7   |   4       |   4
```

So what I would like is that if I'm on Banner 1 edit page and I decide that I no longer want frame 1 to be part of that banner
instead I want Frame 2, Frame 4 and Frame 5. Then I would like the banner_frame table to be updated. So the banner_frame table would end up looking roughly like this

```
id  | banner_id | frame_id
1   |   1       |   2
2   |   2       |   2
3   |   2       |   3
4   |   3       |   3
5   |   3       |   4
6   |   4       |   1
7   |   4       |   4
8   |   1       |   4
9   |   1       |   5
```

At the moment the only thing being updated is the banner title, nothing changes in the banner_frame table

Here is my code

```
<?php
    //GETS THE BANNER FROM THE b_id FROM THE URL
    if(isset($_GET['b_id']))
    {
        $banner_id = $_GET['b_id'];
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM banners WHERE id = $banner_id";

    $select_banner_by_id = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    confirmQuery($select_banner_by_id);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_banner_by_id))
    {
        $banner_id = $row['id'];
        $banner_title = $row['title'];
    }

    //THIS UPDATES THE BANNER
    if(isset($_POST['edit_banner']))
    {
        $banner_title = $_POST['banner_title'];

        $query = "UPDATE banners SET ";
        $query .= "title = '{$banner_title}' ";
        $query .= "WHERE id = $banner_id ";

        $update_banner = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        confirmQuery($update_banner);

        $frames = $_POST['frames'];

        if(!empty($_POST['frames']))
        {
            foreach($_POST['frames'] as $selected_frame)
            {
                // TO UPDATE THE BANNER_FRAME PIVOT TABLE
                $query = "UPDATE banner_frame SET ";
                $query .= "frame_id = $selected_frame, ";
                $query .= "WHERE banner_id = $banner_id, ";

                $create_banner_frame_query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                confirmQuery($create_banner_frame_query);
            }
        }

        //THIS REDIRECTS THE PAGE AFTER SAVING
        header("Location: banners.php");
    }
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="banner_title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="banner_title" value="<?php echo $banner_title ?>">
    </div>

    <!-- BEGIN FRAMES MODAL -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-20" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#frameModal">
        Frames
    </button>

    <!-- MODAL -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="frameModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="frameModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="frameModalLabel">Frames</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php
                    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT f.id as frameId, f.title as frameTitle, bf.banner_id ";
                    $query .= "FROM frames f ";
                    $query .= "LEFT JOIN banner_frame bf ON bf.frame_id = f.id AND bf.banner_id = $banner_id ";
                    $query .= "ORDER BY f.id ";

                    $banner_frame = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                    confirmQuery($banner_frame);

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($banner_frame))
                    {
                        $frame_id = $row['frameId'];
                        $frame_title = $row['frameTitle'];

                        $checked = '';
                        if ($row['banner_id'] == $banner_id) {
                            $checked = 'checked';
                        }

                        echo "<div class='form-check'>";
                        echo    "<input type='checkbox' name='frames[]' id='frame_checkbox' value='$frame_id' $checked> ";
                        echo    "<label for='frame_checkbox'>";
                        echo        $frame_title;
                        echo    "</label>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END FRAMES MODAL -->

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg btn-block" name="edit_banner">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: First of, your update statement has extra unnecessary commas after frame_id = $selected_frame, and WHERE banner_id = $banner_id,

Answer (score 0):

You didn't clearly explain what result your code is currently producing, or give any proper details of your schema etc, but, making (what I hope are) some reasonable assumptions, I would guess that the issue is that the UPDATE statement inside your foreach loop is updating all the frame records for that banner at once every time. And it will also go wrong if the number of selected frames is different to the number previously selected.

What you actually need to do I think is DELETE all the existing frame records for that banner, and then INSERT as many new frame/banner associations into the table as are needed according to the submitted form data.

So you'd first do

```
DELETE FROM banner_frame WHERE banner_id ?
```

(`?` represents the banner ID here, as it should in a properly parameterised query).

And then within the

```
foreach($_POST['frames'] as $selected_frame)
{
```

loop you need to generate a query like

```
INSERT INTO banner_frame (frame_id, banner_id) VALUES (?, ?)
```

where the first `?` is the current `$selected_frame` and the second `?` is the banner ID.

And ideally, all of the above should be wrapped in a transaction to ensure data integrity in the event of an unexpected error.

Comment: I will give that a try. I've also updated my question. I hope my question is better this time.